# How can i implement this?(listfragment, likes Setting Screenshot in Honeycomb)

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

It's a Setting Screenshot of Honeycomb(new users aren't allowed to post images...)
I think it is implemented by using ListFragment, but is it just using Selector?

Because it seems to me that it's a basic application within Honeycomb, I'm thinking that android will support that particular layout...
How will i need to implement this?

Comment: As i got from your question, I think you have to put the divider to the ListView. Or may be you have seen the ListView with section. Please put some more information what you want.

Comment: afaik you can post an url to an image though?

Comment: Screenshot : http://appting.com/data/file/B49/watermark/fb099f013063193ad2c35da04ac67ac6.jpg

Comment: I know how to use the ListView and Style. but what i want to know is if Android supports the basic layout for screenshots like the one i posted here (above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you posted is a settings display implemented using fragments. Look in your SDK directory for /android-13/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/preference. Note that depending on what version of Honeycomb you are using the '13' may be '11', '12','13'. Specifically what you are looking for is is the PreferenceWithHeaders.java file. The headers are the list you see on the left, everything else is fragment preferences.

[EDIT] In light of the comments below, perhaps you should examine how PreferenceActivity builds its Lists. There should be no reason why you cant extract the information you need from this source file (/android-sdks/sources/android-13/android/preference/PreferenceActivity) to see how it builds the lists.

Comment: i see what you said but the layout means designs that include bookmarks.... I know that is prefrence.... thanks for answering

Comment: I am uncertain what you mean by " the layout means designs that include bookmarks.... I know that is prefrence....". If you need them to store other data than basic preferences, you can extend the existing classes to add whatever functionality you need. For example, you could make a "bookmark preference fragment"

Comment: Perhaps i had phrased my question slightly incorrectly. What i wanted to ask was simply regarding the design. I was asking if Andriod had set standards or settings regarding the design (interface) of the screen. simply that. Now, in terms of its functions and inner features, that I know how it is processed. I hope this explanation may be clearer?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you now. There are no hard standards regarding the UI design, however there are definite suggestions, most if not all of which exist to improve the user experience by ensuring that different pieces of software behave similarly so that the user does not have to deal with learning new UI quirks for each new application. See [the Android UI Guidelines here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html) for more details. I'm sorry if I am still misunderstanding your question.

Comment: thanks alot :D
I decided to implement that for myself 
thanks for answering